# Que tipo de problemas as rotas resolvem?

Tags: mvc, terminologia

Todo framework em arquitetura MVC ou até outras arquiteturas que me deparo, encontro quase que obrigatoriedade de configurar rotas. No entanto não está claro para mim que tipo de problema isso resolve, e não encontro literatura que ajude muito. O comum é encotrar conteúdo focado em determinada ferramenta ou framework, tratando as rotas como algo evidente. Django, Angular, Laravel, MVC 5 .NET, praticamente todo material que aborda o assunto trata como se fosse algo que você já aprendeu na faculdade. Eu tenho um palpite intuitivo, tal como eu fazia em requisições GET no PHP. Usava muito para chamar includes, usando o PHP para gerar templates com includes (evitando PHP injection é claro), reaproveitando boa parte do código, e até reescrevendo novos caminhos com poucas linhas de código. Rotas podem ser considerada análoga a essas técnicas primitivas de aplicação web?
Eu acredito que a pergunta **"Que tipo de problemas as rotas resolvem ?"** bem direta e não ampla, espero que interpretem assim, e que ela pode ajudar muitos desenvolvedores. Considerem a edição desse texto como contextualização, e não uma pergunta longa. Obrigado a todos!

Comment: Oi  Sérgio  acho  que essa seria  uma duvida  mais para  o  stack exchange por se  tratar de algo mais téorico do  que tecnico

Comment: As rotas são encotradas em praticamente todos os frameworks existentes, e há amplo conhecimento do que elas fazem. O que não vejo discução é que tipo de problemas na prática elas resolvem. Não há praticamente nada de teórico nisso. A pergunta é bem empírica na verdade, o que por definição não é teórico. 
Em resumo seria: Porque não simplesmente apontar endereços com variáveis ou constantes, porque cada funcionalidade praticamente tem que ter uma rota? Isso me parece bem técnico!

Comment: @MarcosBrinner pausa para ignorar momentaneamente o fato de que muitas perguntas teóricas aqui no site possuem recepção positiva e enorme da comunidade

Comment: As rotas estão em praticamente todos os frameworks, diversas arquiteturas, usamos diariamente, e mesmo assim vc considera isso uma questão teórica?

Comment: Me imagino numa feira perguntando o preço de uma fruta e alguém dizendo que essa é uma questão teórica demais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O SOLID são os princípios da programação a objetos e nos auxilia a escrever códigos melhores. O primeiro é o de Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) ou Princípio da Responsabilidade Única. Esse princípio diz que cada parte do código deve ser responsável por apenas uma tarefa específica.

Com biblioteca de rotas é possível realizar verificações nas entradas (tratando caracteres especiais, por exemplo), trabalhar melhor os verbos http (POST, GET, etc), entre outros.

Na hora de desenvolver o código, as alterações que precisarem ser feitas ficam mais práticas, já que estão concentradas em apenas um lugar.

Veja um exemplo com o Laravel:

```
Route::get( '/',         'OrderController@index' );
Route::get( '/nova',     'OrderController@create');
Route::post('/nova',     'OrderController@store' );
Route::get( '/ver/{id}', 'OrderController@view'  );
```

Com o código organizado dessa forma, é possível alterar as URLs sem maiores problemas, bem como o que cada rota faz.

Answer (score 0):

As rotas resolvem de forma mais fácil o problema de você precisar ter um arquivo físico para cada URL além de permitir escritas de URL mais amigáveis.

Quando ainda não existia o conceito de rotas cada URL era um arquivo físico no servidor .html, .php, .asp, etc. Imagina gerenciar um sistema personalizável que possui mais de 1.000 páginas em arquivos físicos.

De certa forma, pode se parecer com os conceitos de includes. Mas é mais amplo. Pense numa URL que recebe uma requisição de gerar PDF ou Excel. Na maioria das vezes você não precisa de uma página pra isso só devolver o conteúdo para download.